# Why doesn't my ARM LDREX/STREX C function work?

Tags: c, arm, arm64, bare-metal

I wrote a claim_lock function in C, according to the "Barrier Litmus Tests and Cookbook" document. I examined the generated code, and it all looks good, but it didn't work.

```
// This code conforms to the section 7.2 of PRD03-GENC-007826:
// "Acquiring and Releasing a Lock"
static inline void claim_lock( uint32_t volatile *lock )
{
  uint32_t failed = 1;
  uint32_t value;

  while (failed) {
    asm volatile ( "ldrex %[value], [%[lock]]"
                   : [value] "=&r" (value)
                   : [lock] "r" (lock) );
    if (value == 0) {
      // The failed and lock registers are not allowed to be the same, so
      // pretend to gcc that the lock pointer may be written as well as read.

      asm volatile ( "strex %[failed], %[value], [%[lock]]"
                     : [failed] "=&r" (failed)
                     , [lock] "+r" (lock)
                     : [value] "r" (1) );
    }
    else {
      asm ( "clrex" );
    }
  }
  asm ( "dmb sy" );
}
```

Generated code (gcc):

```
1000:       e3a03001        mov     r3, #1
1004:       e1902f9f        ldrex   r2, [r0]
1008:       e3520000        cmp     r2, #0
100c:       1a000004        bne     1024 <claim_lock+0x24>
1010:       e1802f93        strex   r2, r3, [r0]
1014:       e3520000        cmp     r2, #0
1018:       1afffff9        bne     1004 <claim_lock+0x4>
101c:       f57ff05f        dmb     sy
1020:       e12fff1e        bx      lr
1024:       f57ff01f        clrex
1028:       eafffff5        b       1004 <claim_lock+0x4>
```

Corresponding release function:

```
static inline void release_lock( uint32_t volatile *lock )
{
  // Ensure that any changes made while holding the lock are
  // visible before the lock is seen to have been released
  asm ( "dmb sy" );
  *lock = 0;
}
```

It worked in QEMU, but either hung, or allowed all cores to "claim" the so-called "lock" on real hardware (Raspberry Pi 3 Cortex-A53).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LDREX instruction will hang the core (unless my test failed to report an exception) if:

- The MMU is not enabled
- The virtual memory area containing the lock is not cached

The cores will appear to ignore each other's claims if:

- Symmetric Multi-processing has not been enabled

The SMP enable mechanism seems to vary from device to device; check the TRM for the partular core, it's outside the scope of the ARM ARM.

For the Cortex-A53, the bit to set is SMPEN, bit 6 of The CPU Extended Control Register, CPUECTLR.

Earlier devices have bit 5 of the Auxiliary Control Register, for example (ARM11 MPcore), where there's also the SCU to consider. I don't have such a device, but it's that documentation where I first noticed an SMP/nAMP bit.

Comment: `The MMU is not enabled`, `The virtual memory area containing the lock is not cached`. Cache is disabled when MMU is off. And having lock in cache to make it works smells fishy. You probably missing to set up cache-coherency between cores properly.

Comment: Yes. Once enabled, the MMU can have areas of memory that aren't cached, and unless I've missed something else, using ldrex/strex in those areas does not work. And, yes, I had failed to set up cache-coherency between cores properly, the SMP bit has to be set, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: you definitely missed something, having 'lock' in cache to have it working is not a solution

Comment: OK, so how do you get locks that aren't in a cached area to work? My observation is that they don't.

Comment: You are fixed on a caching, while that's not a cause of a problem but a symptom. You telling that 'lock' has to be in cache or otherwise that does not work. So let say cpu0 has cached lock, and cpu1 has non-cached lock. cpu0 acquires lock, cpu1 is trying to read it from memory (not cache) while lock-data in memory is outdated and does not match data in cache. That indicates that cache-coherence is not set up properly. As an option try to flush cache after writing lock and invalidate cache before reading lock.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's not that, because the instruction following the LDREX on a non-cached address (for that core, let alone others) doesn't seem to get executed, whereas it does on a cached one. Do you have some document that says what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i found in Context switch section of ARMv7-M Architecture
Reference Manual

> Blockquote

It is necessary to ensure that the local monitor is in the Open Access state after a context switch. In
ARMv7-M, the local monitor is changed to Open Access automatically as part of an exception entry or exit
sequence. The local monitor can also be forced to the Open Access state by a CLREX instruction.
Note
Context switching is not an application level operation. However, this information is included here to
complete the description of the exclusive operations.
A context switch might cause a subsequent Store-Exclusive to fail, requiring a load … store sequence to be
replayed. To minimize the possibility of this happening, ARM recommends that the Store-Exclusive
instruction is kept as close as possible to the associated Load-Exclusive instruction, see Load-Exclusive and
Store-Exclusive usage restrictions.

> Blockquote

Comment: Yes. I think the above code ensures that the Store-Exclusive instruction is kept as close as possible to the associated Load-Exclusive instruction, there are only two instructions between them.